# How to seal an oiled table

Tags: wood, woodworking, table, sealant, oil

My mom owns a walnut table. It was recently sanded, cleaned and oiled, but now even the slightest movement on the table stains and scratches. Even cleaning the table with a damp cloth affects the finish. We were wondering how to properly seal the table, considering most sealants don't really work with oil.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe its bern over-oiled. Try buffing it with soft cloth.